# How to reset a query in MySQL CLI client

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to undo a query in the MySQL Linux CLI client?

In other words, if I'm using the mysql CLI client, and if I type a wrong query, is there a way to reset the last query buffer instead of deleting everything that I just typed?

Pressing Ctrl+C and Ctrl+D exits out of the program completely.

And I have gone through the documentation but haven't found anything related to this topic.

Comment: What do you mean by reseting a query? Have you tried clicking the up arrow in your keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean, but you an use cursor up and cursor down to scroll through the history. Maybe MySQL CLI needs to be compiled with `readline` support for that, but at least for me, I never encountered a MySQL CLI without that working.

Maybe you want to know how to clear the input line? `Ctrl+U` can be used for that.

When inside `mysql`, you can enter `help` to get help. `\c` will clear the input statement.

Comment: Well I am looking for a way to just "clear" the current query. Ctrl+U only clears the current line so if I have a multi-line query, it won't clear the entire query - just the current line. However, Ctrl+U is something I did not know about so I will award you the points. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I now added the really expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to rollback queries in MySQL after they have been executed. The only way to revert data to a previous state would be to load a previous backup.

You did make a backup of the database before you executed a possibly dangerous query right? :)

Comment: I'm not looking to undo or rollback the previously executed query. I'm just trying to see if there is a way to revert everything I have entered for the *current* query. So if I enter a multi-line query and if I entered something incorrectly in the previous line, I want to be able to just get rid of everything that was entered. I learned from Shi that Ctrl+U can clear the input line, so it's something close to what I'm looking for. What I really want is something that will clear the entire query that was entered. Again, I'm not looking to undo the previously executed query. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should have just asked if there is a way to access the previously entered queries. That behavior can be achieved by simply pressing the up / down arrows, just like in any other shell that supports command history.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to clear the current query. Behavior similar to Ctrl+U.